# Using weight function to construct a minimum

Tags: numerical-methods

I have a continuous, bounded function $f(x)$ and a weight function $w(x)$ on the same interval. If

$$\{\phi_i(x)\}^N_{i=0}$$

is a family of basis functions for a linear space and $N>0$, I need to find

$$g(x)=\sum^N_{i=0}a_i\,\phi_i(x)$$

such that

$$\int|f(x)-g(x)|^2 w(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

is a minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that $w$ is bdd, and bdd away form zero.

Define the scalar product $(f, g) := \int f g w$ with corresponding norm $|\cdot|$.

Let $V_N$ be spanned by $\phi_0, \ldots, \phi_N$.

The question is: given $f$, find $g \in V_N$ such that $|f - g|$ is minimized. Thus $g$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$ onto $V_N$ wrt the scalar product $(\cdot, \cdot)$. It is characterized by 
$$
(g, \psi) = (f, \psi) \quad \forall \psi \in V_N.
$$

This is equivalent to
$$
(g, \phi_i) = (f, \phi_i) \quad \forall 0 \leq i \leq N
.
$$

Writing $g = \sum_j a_j \phi_j$ this becomes
$$
\sum_j (\phi_j, \phi_i) a_j = (f, \phi_i)
\quad \forall 0 \leq i \leq N
.
$$

Define the $(N+1)^2$ Gramian matrix $M$ with the components $M_{ij} = (\phi_j, \phi_i)$. The above is equivalent to the matrix-vector equation
$$
M a = b
$$
where $b_i = (f, \phi_i)$.